# WebSocket handshake error in production but not development

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, socket.io

I am making a Node app that uses Socket.IO. In development it works fine, but after deploying to Heroku I am getting the following error. I am very new to sockets so I have no idea why. I think this is causing the site to be very laggy, thoughts? I thought I was supposed to set port to `process.env.PORT`.

> WebSocket connection to `'ws://www.pokemania.site/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=yoSrzf60h9oNg3sVAAAG'` failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

Code:

```
const app = require("http").createServer(handler);
const io = require("socket.io")(app);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT);

new Sockets(io);
```

Comment: What is `Sockets`?

Comment: You may want to check to see if Heroku requires a specific configuration in order to support webSocket connections since they are sometimes handled differently by the load balancer/proxies that hosting companies often use in front of your server.

Comment: Thanks - I am using socket.IO. Sockets is just a wrapper class that takes care of client connect, disconnect, etc. The issue is the handshake though :(